# Appendix letter missing

Tags: appendices

I am writing documents using apa6.
I don't get an Appendix letter but figures and tables are labeled with and appendix letter prefix. I cannot find the problem.

Here is the code I use.

```
\documentclass[11pt,doc]{apa6} 
\DeclareGraphicsRule{.tif}{png}{.png}{`convert #1 `dirname #1`/`basename #1 .tif`.png}
\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor, colortbl}
\usepackage{soul}
\usepackage[dutch]{babel} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{csquotes}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{nameref}

\usepackage{setspace}  
\usepackage[inline]{enumitem}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem} 
\usepackage{array} 
\usepackage{multirow}
\usepackage{lscape}
\usepackage{pdflscape} 
\usepackage{fancyhdr}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[dutch]{varioref} 


\usepackage[style=apa,sortcites=true,sorting=nyt,backend=biber]{biblatex}
\DeclareLanguageMapping{dutch}{dutch-apa}

\definecolor{Gray}{gray}{0.90} 
\definecolor{C_TableRow}{gray}{0.90} 
\definecolor{C_TableTop}{rgb}{1,1,0.8} 


 % command for cell alignment in tables
\newcolumntype{L}[1]{>{\raggedright\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}p{#1}} % p aligns to top; m towards center and b to the bottom
\newcolumntype{C}[1]{>{\centering\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}
\newcolumntype{R}[1]{>{\raggedleft\let\newline\\\arraybackslash\hspace{0pt}}m{#1}}

% element counter that I use in tables
\newcounter{item-nr} \setcounter{item-nr}{0}
\newcommand{\nextItem}{\stepcounter{item-nr}\arabic{item-nr}}
 \newcommand{\firstItem}{\setcounter{item-nr}{1}\arabic{item-nr}}

\title{Design}
\shorttitle{ Instruction Design}
\author{John Whatever}
\affiliation{
\vfill
\footnotesize{Onderwijs}
}


\abstract{ Samenvatting abstract}


\keywords{Design of Instruction, Instruction Design}



\begin{document}
\maketitle

\section {Start of ducument}
Dit is de inhoud van het document


\printbibliography

\appendix

\section{\textbf{Section with first attachement}}
The reference to the Table \vref{tab:tab1} shows there is an Appendix letter.

\begin{table}[h]
\renewcommand{\arraystretch}{1.3}
\begin{threeparttable}
\centering
\caption{ Table in Appendix } \label{tab:tab1}
\begin{tabular}{R{1.5cm} L{12cm} R{1cm}}
\hline
\rowcolor{C_TableTop}
\small{Req nr.} & \textbf{Element description }& \textbf{some id} \\
\hline
R\firstItem& Element 1&1\\

R\nextItem &  Element 2 & 1.1\\

\hline
\end{tabular}
\end{threeparttable}
\end {table}


\end{document}
```

Any suggestion is welcome to get the appendix letter in place.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! The `apa6` class only adds a letter to the title of an appendix if there are at least two of them.

Comment: Your question is a mix of English and Dutch and difficult to read.

Comment: Off-topic: The instruction `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames]{xcolor, colortbl}` isn't right. It should be `\usepackage[usenames,dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}`.

Comment: Put \renewcommand{\thetable}{\arabic{table}} after the first section in the appendix.

Answer (score 1):

The `apa6` class adds letters to the section titles in the appendix only if there's more than one section.

You get the letter nonetheless if you do

```
\global\oneappendixfalse
\appendix
```

so as to override the standard mechanism in `apa6.cls`.